# Matching lines of text in a UTF16-LE file

Tags: python, utf-16

I'm parsing a file that's written in UTF16-LE for fairly simple matches and none of them seem to trigger. For example, I have the following code.

```
with open(filepath) as f:
   for line in f:
      if 'TEST_CASE' in line:
         print(line)
```

Is there a good way to check the lines in the file for matches without altering the file itself?

Comment: Have you tried `codecs.open('file', encoding='UTF16-LE')` ?

Comment: I am assuming there's a `for line in f:` somewhere there?

Comment: You assume correctly, my bad.

Comment: @JonClements That seems to have worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment `codecs.open('filename', encoding='utf-16-le')`